# Update Canvas and holder

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am starting with canvas and i need help.
I want to represent real times coordinates in a "room". First when i create surfaceholder i draw the "room" and works fine. My idea is represents differents point in this room.

This is my activity:

```
package com.example.grafica;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LayoutInflater myInflater = null;
    private TextView tx1, tx2, tx3, tx4, tx5, tx6, tx7;
    float ancho = (float) 5.20;
    float largo = (float) 3.50;
    private TableLayout table, table2;
    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams params, params2;
    private MySurface surface;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("telo", "oncreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View overView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.segundacapa, null);
            this.addContentView(overView, new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        }

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View overView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.segundacapaland, null);
            this.addContentView(overView, new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        }

        surface =(MySurface)findViewById(R.id.surface);
        tx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tx3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tx4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        tx5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        tx6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        tx7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {

            table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
            params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) table.getLayoutParams();

            float ratio = ancho / largo;
            float aux = width / ratio;

            params.topMargin = (int) aux + 20;

            surface.xini = 20;
            surface.yini = 20;
            surface.xend = width - 20;
            surface.yend = aux;

        }

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            table2 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);
            params2 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) table2.getLayoutParams();

            float ratio = largo / ancho;
            float aux = width / ratio;

            params2.leftMargin = (int) (width * ratio) + 20;

            surface.xini = 20;
            surface.yini = 20;
            surface.xend = width * ratio;
            surface.yend = height - 220;

        }

        surface.ini();
        surface.update();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent evento) {

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, evento);
    }
}
```

And this my surface class:

```
package com.example.grafica;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Paint pincel = new Paint();
    private Canvas canvas;
    public float xini = 0;
    public float yini = 0;
    public float xend = 0;
    public float yend = 0;
    public float coordinatex =(float) 2.50;
    public float coordinatety=(float) 1.75;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    public MySurface(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context,attr);


    }

    public void ini(){
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    public void update(){

        holder.lockCanvas();
        pincel.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        pincel.setStrokeWidth(25);
        canvas.drawPoint(100, 100, pincel);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

        holder = arg0;
        canvas = arg0.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        pincel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        pincel.setStrokeWidth(8);
        pincel.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        RectF rect = new RectF();

        rect.set(xini, yini, xend, yend);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, pincel);

        pincel.setColor(Color.RED);
        pincel.setStrokeWidth(25);
        canvas.drawPoint(xini, yend, pincel);

        pincel.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        pincel.setStrokeWidth(25);
        canvas.drawPoint(xend, yend, pincel);

        pincel.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        pincel.setStrokeWidth(25);
        canvas.drawPoint(xini, yini, pincel);

        pincel.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        pincel.setStrokeWidth(25);
        canvas.drawPoint(xend, yini, pincel);

        arg0.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        Log.e("surfaceDestroyed ", "Hilo detenido ");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    }

}
```

In conclussion, with `surface.ini();` i call to SurfaceCreated and draw the room, and my idea is that with `surface.upddate();` represents a point in this room. It is possible reuse same canvas and holder? how? 
I read something about invalidate() function, could be help me? how use this function?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a thread to manage the view redrawing effect :

From run method either :

- Code your drawing method
- Call directly onDraw

Here is an example [Example on how to subclass and use SurfaceView](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/simple-surfaceview-example-t2174100.html)